# Getting the Correct SQL Query Syntax for MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, sqlanywhere

I am converting some SQL queries to run against MariaDB instead of via SQL Anywhere. One part of the query I need to update looks like this:

```
and datepart(mm,c.dob) = datepart(mm,today()) + 1
```

After consulting some MariaDB documentation, I think the second part may need to be this:

```
MONTH(NOW()) + 1
```

But, I'm not sure how to re-create the logic from the original line, since `datepart` is not used in MariaDB. When I try this, the query runs:

```
and MONTH(c.dob) = MONTH(NOW()) + 1
```

Does this look like the correct replacement syntax?

Comment: Did you forget part of your second code? It is incomplete or otherwise doesn't do what the first piece of code does.

Comment: Just realized that. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Technically, they would be equivalent.  I'm not sure that either is "correct", because month 13 doesn't exist.

Comment: `month(c.dob) = month(now()) + 1` would be equivalent, but I agree with Gordon that it's not good logic. It will skip all the January babies.

Comment: Okay, so it is equivalent, but not good logic. What would be better altogether then?

Comment: Maybe something like: `month(c.dob) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))`:  "Does the date of birth occur next month"

Comment: "better altogether" would require an understanding of the intent.  If you're trying to just return all birthdays next month then I think JNevill has it; but if you're after something else; we need to understand the intent/requirement  better.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a column inside a function call prevents use of an index.  Try to avoid such.

When doing date arithmetic, use syntax like this:

```
 date_value + INTERVAL 4 DAY
```

If using `MONTH(NOW())`, what should you expect in December?

You can treat dates as strings in the format `2019-09-06`, so this is one way to get the start of the current month:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01');
+---------------------+-----------------------------------+
| NOW()               | CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 2019-09-06 11:38:37 | 2019-09-01                        |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Hence this will give you the start of next month, even in December:

```
CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

It is usually preferable to compare dates than to pick apart a date -- I am thinking of the December issue.  And leap-day.

```
WHERE my_date >= CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

will check for `my_date` being next month (or later).  This works whether `my_date` is `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`.

But, since `dob` is "date of birth", most of what I say is irrelevant, and you really need `MONTH(dob)`